# Identify Column Header and copy rows data under corresponding column header to different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, header

I have a sheet where a person selects a week and a year, and for that week it inputs data from rows 7 to row 28 (column D).

I created a formula based header that takes the week & year and creates a unique header (in cell D2) identifiable in the second sheet where the data should go.

I need to write some VBA code to identify the data by the "current" header and paste it in the other sheet under its respective header.

I tried to copy paste the columns via VBA but don't know how to identify the headers and paste under the particular one.

Sheet to copy from:

[image: sheet to copy from]

Sheet to paste in:

[image: sheet to paste in]

Comment: Why don't you share the worksheets' and tables' names and a screenshot of them? Also, add the code you've tried. If you don't have a code, create one with the macro recorder: START, select the range (`H5:H29`), copy, select the destination worksheet, paste into the appropriate first cell, select the source worksheet, STOP.

Comment: i shared the worksheets

Comment: What are the worksheet names? Do you have a source worksheet for each year? How should the code run? Via a button or automatically when the user fills `D1` and `E1`? Could you share the rows of the destination worksheet?

Comment: the worksheet where the user inputs data is called "Current Week Target". The sheet where the data will be copied is "FCST Data". the sheet will be used for multiple years. The code should run by pressing a button after it fills the data.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Matching Column Range (`Application.Match`)

```vb
Sub CopyWeekData()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Current Week Target")
    
    Dim MatchWeek As String: MatchWeek = CStr(sws.Range("D1").Value)
    Dim MatchYearWeek As String: MatchYearWeek = CStr(sws.Range("D2").Value)
    
    Dim scIndex As Variant ' could be an error value
    scIndex = Application.Match(MatchWeek, sws.Rows(4), 0)
    
    If IsError(scIndex) Then
        MsgBox "Week not found in source.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Rows("5:30").Columns(scIndex)
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    
    '!!! Adjust the 2 and the 5 appropriately. Can't be seen in the screenshot!!!
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("FCST Data")
    
    Dim dcIndex As Variant ' could be an error value
    dcIndex = Application.Match(MatchYearWeek, dws.Rows(2), 0)
    
    If IsError(dcIndex) Then
        MsgBox "Year/Week not found in destination.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Cells(5, dcIndex).Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
    
    ' Copy values.
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Week data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm very thankful to you. If I can ever return the favor message me

Comment: This works , but I noticed if W1 is selected it doesnt copy the values, for every other week it works

Comment: What do you mean? I tested it only with `W1`. Which message box appears?

Comment: it didnt appear any message, it just didnt copy any values, it was showing "-" for each box. However i managed to work around it, as in reality I only need to MatchYearWeek, and MatchWeek wont be necessary. Now it works, thank you again